# Implementing ssl pinning in a react-native application using TrustKit iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, trustkit

I'm trying to implement SSL pinning in a react-native application (RN 0.60) and I'm using Trustkit.

Following the guide posted in https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit these are the step that I've done:

1) Install TrustKit pod using `pod 'TrustKit'` and `pod install`

2) Added to my `AppDelegate.m` this piece of code:

```
#import <TrustKit/TrustKit.h>

//inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

NSDictionary *trustKitConfig =
  @{
    kTSKSwizzleNetworkDelegates: @YES,
    kTSKPinnedDomains: @{
        @"www.datatheorem.com" : @{
            kTSKEnforcePinning:@YES,
            kTSKIncludeSubdomains:@YES,
            //Using wrong hashes so it fails
            kTSKPublicKeyHashes : @[
                @"Ca5gV6n7OVx4AxtEaIk8NI9qyKBTtKJjwqullb/v9hh=",
                @"YLh1dUR9y6Kja30RrAn7JKnbQG/uEtLMkBgFF2Fuihh="
                ]
            }}};

  [TrustKit initSharedInstanceWithConfiguration:trustKitConfig];
```

When i try to do

```
 RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', "https://www.datatheorem.com", {})    //tried using standard fetch() but gives same results
    .then(async(res) => {
        console.log('RES => ' ,res)
    })
    // Something went wrong:
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('ERROR =>', err);
    })
```

It goes inside `then` and doesn't give any error but responds with a 200 status code (using wrong Hashes).

Otherwise, using Android it works correctly, going inside the catch and saying:

```
Error: Pin verification failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I've came back to this and tried it out again and got it working. The only difference from my current code to the one i posted some time ago is that i added `kTSKPublicKeyAlgorithms : @[kTSKAlgorithmRsa2048]` inside a specific pinned domain.

I've followed the same steps i posted in the question. The final `AppDelegate` looks like:

Inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` before the `return YES`, i added:

```
  [self initTrustKit];
```

Then after the enclosing parenthesis of the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` i added:

```
- (void)initTrustKit {
      NSDictionary *trustKitConfig =
  @{
    kTSKSwizzleNetworkDelegates: @YES,                    
    kTSKPinnedDomains : @{
            @"www.datatheorem.com" : @{
              kTSKEnforcePinning : @YES,
              kTSKIncludeSubdomains:@YES,
                    kTSKPublicKeyHashes : @[
                        @"Ca5gV6n7OVx4AxtEaIk8NI9qyKBTtKJjwqullb/v9hh=",
                        @"YLh1dUR9y6Kja30RrAn7JKnbQG/uEtLMkBgFF2Fuihh="
                            ],
              kTSKPublicKeyAlgorithms : @[kTSKAlgorithmRsa2048],
                    },
            }};
    [TrustKit initSharedInstanceWithConfiguration:trustKitConfig];
}
```

Not it works in iOS returning going in the catch and printing : `ERROR => cancelled`

Comment: Have you tried to run Charles log after implemetation? is it working ?

Answer (score 0):

I have configure the `TrustKit` in the `Info.plist`.
Also I notice that even though you have only 1 `PublicKeyHash`, you have to provide a dummy one as well for `Trustkit` to work in iOS apps.

Comment: In the example I posted there are 2 hashes. I used the appDelegate method as it’s more readable (for me) than using the info.plist . Or were you talking about something else?

Comment: Yes. Your example is correct. I mean when I doing my project, I just put 1 hash and the app is crashes upon build. After checking for few hours and found out that the app crashes due to missing backup hash. Just to share my experience that 2 hashes must be provided.